# Display form without blocking execution of program

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to show a simple form (that just displays a label) from within a function of my DLL. However, I need this form to be displayed without blocking the execution of this function (e.g. show form and continue execution of function.)

I've tried using just:

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

However this is obviously a modal dialog, so blocks the execution until the user interacts with it. I've also tried using:

```
form.Show();
```

But this causes the form to load behind all other windows, and the controls don't load properly (just show blank boxes where they should be.)

To try and combat these problems, I've tried creating and showing the form on a new thread both like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(ShowXForm);
thread.Start();
```

and like this:

```
new Thread(delegate ()
{
    ShowXForm();
}).Start();
```

where:

```
private void ShowXForm()
{
    frmX XForm = new frmX();
    XForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Again, these lead to almost the same behavior as simply using Show without creating a new thread.

An added difficulty with it running on a different thread is that I still need to be able to update the label on the form from the main thread (could be achieved using delegates?)

I am aware that it is good practice to have the main thread as the UI thread, however with this being a DLL rather than a Windows form app, it feels like the UI should perhaps not be running on the main thread.

Comment: Can you show how the function within your DLL is being called?  Are you calling it from within a .Net windows form app?

Comment: After just seeing the exact opposite on another question, I have to say:  This shows excellent effort on your part.  My first thought was "separate thread", but then I saw you've tried that.  I wish I could give you a better answer.

Comment: I am asking how you are calling it, because I remember a COM exposed C# dll you were asking about the other day and I am wondering if this is a related question. Are you trying to invoke this method via a COM call?

Comment: With that separate thread, did you try showing the form (`XForm.Show()`), telling the form to go to the top (on load do something like `this.BringToFront()`), and setting a timer on it that would close it (if it's a message you only want to show temporarily)?

Comment: @pstrjds It is related to the same project I was asking about the other day, but this function isn't called directly via COM. I'm unsure how this would affect what I'm trying to achieve though?

Comment: @tj_ush - I am wondering if you have access to the main form (if it is a windows form) and can then call this method via `BeginInvoke`. I think if you can call this method via `BeginInvoke` (or `Invoke` if you want it to block until completion) that this will solve your issues. You should be able to just call `Show` on the form and it should render properly (although you may have to make a call to `BringToFront` as it could still render behind). If you don't have access to the main form, you could try `Application.Run` in this method which will put it in its own message loop.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any scope to access the main form, could a similar approach to this be achieved without having access to this? I've already tried using Application.Run() but this didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: So, did you try combining a separate thread, using `.Show()`, and bringing the form to the Front (`this.BringToFront()`) on the load event of `frmX`?  And what exactly does that combination do wrong or fail to do?

Comment: @AgapwIesu Yep, I've tried this. It needs Application.Run otherwise the form doesn't show at all, and even so it still causes the form to load behind all other windows and also shows a loading wheel when hovering over it so you can't even close/minimize it etc

Comment: @pstrjds Forgot to tag you in the above comment, any ideas?

Comment: `Application.Run()`, passing in your form, **inside** a thread is most likely what you're looking for...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Passing my form to Application.Run doesn't appear to make any difference. The form does eventually appear when the method completely finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

The call to Application.Run() needs to be **INSIDE** a new thread.

Something like...

```
private void ShowXForm()
{    
    new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        frmX XForm = new frmX();
        Application.Run(XForm);
    }).Start();
}
```

If you want to have it update, though, you'll have to keep that form reference out at class level and give it a mechanism to pass updates and have that form correctly marshal that call to itself with a delegate/Invoke().

Comment: I was starting to add a suggested answer of this nature, but one thing I think you need to do is to set the `ApartmentState` on that thread to STA. So you need to separate the creation from the start call so that you can set it to STA.

Comment: I've just tried this code with the ApartmentState set as well (as suggested by @pstrjds).

`private void ShowNotificationsForm()
 {
     Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
      {
          frmNotifications notificationsForm = new frmNotifications();
          Application.Run(notificationsForm);
       });
       thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       thread.Start();`

However, this still doesn't behave any differently. Perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: One interesting observation is that it doesn't seem like the form is even created until a thread.sleep is hit later in the code?

Comment: @tj_ush - it sounds to me like there is a lot of other stuff going on then and it is probably going to be difficult for us to diagnose/suggest without seeing more of what you are doing. Like, where is this `Thread.Sleep` you are talking about? How is your code wired into the main code? Are you just implementing an interface and your dll is being injected at runtime?

Comment: @pst Apologies, I only posted the code which I thought would be relevant to the question. Okay, so to give a quick overview of the code. As you say, this is just an interface and the DLL is being injected at runtime. There's a function that is called via COM (function A) - this performs several steps, including calling into the function (X) to which the question refers. Function X makes a number of HTTP requests and the outcome of these requests should be displayed within the form.

Comment: The code in this function (e.g. further HTTP requests and processing) needs to continue running without being blocked by the UI, but similarly the UI needs to display/update without being blocked by the processing. Due to the set up, it doesn't seem right to have the main thread as the UI thread as convention would dictate.

Comment: @tj_ush - From what you described, the suggested answer should solve your problem. Maybe you are blocking it in some other way. I am assuming you did not add a `Join` call to the thread that is being launched or something like that. Maybe there is something else that is causing this to not work. You could go a little further outside the box and make this into its own exe and have method A launch it. You could use some form of [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) to push data between the two.

Comment: I can't see anything else that would be blocking it? No join or anything like that. I have been debugging it as an exe to simplify things. I'm genuinely baffled by this, it's almost as if the thread isn't actually getting started until the entirety of function A has finished executing?